# Playing music regardless or url in HTML sites?

Tags: mp3, frameset

I know you can either open a separate window, use Flash or frames (yuk) to display an mp3 player that continually plays audio regardless of which page you're on. But I've just seen this site here that appears to do it without frames, Flash or a separate window and was wondering how they do it?

http://www.killertracks.com/#/browse.aspx

Looks like they're using JavaScript to load the songs, but evern when I got to a different URL in the site, the music keeps playing. Any ideas how I could do that? Got a site I'm building at the moment that needs this featured.

Thanks,

Osu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the audio is being played in a Flash player :-)

However, while the audio is playing all pages are loaded via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and made navigable via the [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

You can see this in Chrome, for example, by pressing F12, selecting the *Network* tab, then clicking on a link. If there is a `themed-playlists.aspx` listed, click on it and in the **Request Headers** section you will see `X-Requested-With:`[`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) which is the API that JavaScript is using to load the new page dynamically without navigating away from the current page. The *new page* is then used to update the content on the current page to make it look like the new page. Many websites use this mechanism to dynamically update a page without a full page load.

For example, as I am typing this answer, JavaScript is periodically sending my answer to the stackoverflow server and saving it as a draft. This is completely transparent to my interaction with the main page.

Another great site that uses this method is the [BBC Music Showcase](http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/showcase), however it dynamically plays both audio *and* video whilst allowing you to navigate the site!

Comment: That's amazing, thanks for explaining that - must be a huge load of work to do something like that though right? Also, it means the site relies on JavaScript to function properly (not that it bothers me all that much as I have JS on, but standardistas would reel I expect). I don't suppose it would be possible to implement in a Wordpress site right? At least not easily...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with html5, you can access the audio api directly in javascript.

eg.

```
var sound = new Audio("file.mp3"); 
sound.play();
```

See an article like this for example: `http://www.storiesinflight.com/jsfft/visualizer/index.html`

So basically you would be capturing the button/link event in javascript and running javascript code like this to play the sound. Only works with html5 browsers tho, but most modern browsers support it :) - for browsers that dont support maybe you can download the swf audio players currently out there (with these can you trigger sounds using javascript apis provided).